# Align text when written list of tuples to txt file

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

I'm trying to write a list of tuples into txt file and align it to the left. (need to be separated by tabs)
this is the list of tuples:

```
list1 = [(1, "Banana", "Yellow"), (2 , "Apple", "Red"), (3, "Carrot", "Orange")]
```

this is the code I wrote:

```
def write_fruit(list1,new_file):
if not isinstance(list1, list):
    raise ValueError("First input must be a list.")
header = "Num Fruit Color"
with open(new_file, "w") as output:
    output.write(header + "\n")
    for line in list1:
        if not isinstance(line[1], str):
            raise ValueError("Second input must be a str.")
        vals = " ".join(str(i) for i in line)
        output.write(vals + "\n")
print(write_fruit(fruit_list, "fruit_list.txt"))
```

my txt file looks like this:

```
Num  Fruit  Color
 1  Banana    Yellow
 2   Apple   Red
 3   Carrot    Orange
```

I need it to be align to the left and I saw some suggestions looking like that {: >20} but didn't really understand the logic behind it so Ill be happy if there's different way to do it.

Comment: First : I don't see any tabs `\t`, you using space only

Comment: Use a formatting method, you can specify field widths there.

Comment: I don't see how you're getting that text file as a result. Your code only puts one space between each field, but you have different numbers of spaces on each line.

Comment: What logic don't you understand? The formatting operator `{:>20}` means to put the corresponding value in a 20-character field with left alignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest [basic python formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) with `"{:<5}{:10}{:10}\n"`

- `{:<5}` means 5-length minimum with space padding, align to left, when `{:>5}` means align to right
- `{:10}` means 10-length minimum with space padding.

Default numeric align is *right* so we have to force *left*, whereas default for string is already *left*

---

```
def write_fruit(list1, new_file):
    if not isinstance(list1, list):
        raise ValueError("First input must be a list.")
    template = "{:<5}{:10}{:10}\n"
    header = "Num Fruit Color".split()
    with open(new_file, "w") as output:
        output.write(template.format(*header))
        for line in list1:
            if not isinstance(line[1], str):
                raise ValueError("Second input must be a str.")
            output.write(template.format(*line))
```

Giving

```
Num  Fruit     Color     
1    Banana    Yellow    
2    Apple     Red       
3    Carrot    Orange
```

Comment: The OP said he didn't understand previous answers that use `{:>20}`. So you need to explain what that's doing.

Comment: @Barmar Just finished redacting it

Comment: Thats great! Im kinda new to it and just learning the basics, that was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

For proper alignment, change this

```
header = "Num Fruit Color"
```

to this

```
header = "Num\tFruit\tColor"
```

and change this,

```
vals = " ".join(str(i) for i in line)
```

to this

```
vals = "\t".join(str(i) for i in line)
```

So your code becomes:

```
def write_fruit(list1,new_file):
    if not isinstance(list1, list):
        raise ValueError("First input must be a list.")
    header = "Num\tFruit\tColor"
    with open(new_file, "w") as output:
        output.write(header + "\n")
        for line in list1:
            if not isinstance(line[1], str):
                    raise ValueError("Second input must be a str.")
            vals = "\t".join(str(i) for i in line)
            output.write(vals + "\n")

fruit_list = [(1, "Banana", "Yellow"), (2 , "Apple", "Red"), (3, "Carrot", "Orange")]
print(write_fruit(fruit_list, "fruit_list.txt"))
```

giving output in output file as:

```
Num Fruit   Color
1   Banana  Yellow
2   Apple   Red
3   Carrot  Orange
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess that for the align I should use the "\t" rather then the "\n|